# Maximum value of function $f(x)=\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^6+2x^3-1}$ when $x >1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

What is the maximum value of the $$f(x)=\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^6+2x^3-1}$$ where $x > 1$ .

#### My try

[image: Image 1]

Unable to solve further.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ on the second page?

Comment: Hint: the derivative can be written as
$$
f'(x) = \frac{-2x(x^2 +1)(x^2-x-1)(x^4 + x^3 - x^2 - x -1)}{(x^6 + 2x^3 -1)^2}
$$
Source: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+(x%5E4-x%5E2)%2F(x%5E6+%2B+2x%5E3+-1)

Comment: $f(x)$ would be maximum when $1/f(x)$ would be minimum.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x-\frac{1}{x}=t$.

Thus, $t>0$ and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^6+2x^3-1}=\frac{x-\frac{1}{x}}{x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}+2}=\frac{t}{t^3+3t+2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{t^2+\frac{2}{t}+3}\leq\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{t^2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2}+3}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
The equality occurs for $t=1$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Brilliant answer as always! How did you come up with that substitution? Was it very obvious? :P